# How to Roll a Check on Roll20 Via Chat Commands?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, roll20

So, me and my friends are playing D&D 3.5 using the default sheet template complete with macros and all.

The problem is, when I ask for them to roll a check, they have to search for it on their sheet, or have the button ready on their hotbar, which would cause a real clutter for them, if all of the checks and rolls were there. That is a real pain for me too, when I have to play as an absent player.

That's why I would like to know if there is any command, or /roll argument, to roll checks easily from the chat, as the sheet buttons themselves have names and could probably be referenced.

***Note: We are not Pro Subscribers (yet).***

Comment: I'll be testing all the solutions presented as soon as I have time and then choose my answer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: See also [an answer I posted](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/123632/31471) on a similar question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you mouse-over a check on a character sheet, the name of the associated macro should be appearing. To use it from the chat, type `%{`**complete** name of the character`|`name of the macro`}`.

If a token represents the character, you can also select it and use the command `%{selected|`name of the macro`}`.

The names of the check depend of the sheet version, and I'm note sure if you can customize them. Fortunately, they're often logical and not too hard to remember. For instance, the Use Rope check is `useropecheck`.

Comment: Yes this is less convoluted than my method. I will leave my answer up because that will allow people get into the nuts and bolts of the character sheet to craft their own custom rolls.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible and it not difficult to use. What is difficult is finding out the names of the different modifiers.

**Once you know the modifier's name**.

The basic command for rolling a check in Roll20 is

> /roll 1d20

The easiest way to manage this for a PC that you, the referee control is to create a token and assign it as representing that CHARACTER (not the player, but the character). Select that token and then you can do this.

> /roll 1d20+@{selected|str-mod}

You can replace str-mod with the name of anything on the character sheet.

**OR**

> /roll 1d20+@{*(character name)*|str-mod}

**Common Names for 3.5**

**Attributes**

- str-mod
- dex-mod
- con-mod
- int-mod
- wis-mod
- cha-mod

**Saves**

- fortitude
- reflex
- will

**Skills**

- appraise
- balance
- bluff
- climb
- concentration
- craft1
- craft2
- craft3
- decipherscript
- diplomacy
- disabledevice
- disguise
- escapeartist
- forgery
- gatherinformation
- handleanimal
- heal
- hide
- intimidate
- jump
- knowarcana
- knowengineer
- knowdungeon
- knowgeography
- knowhistory
- knowlocal
- knownature
- knowability
- knowreligion
- knowplanes
- listen
- movesilent
- openlock
- perform1
- perform2
- perform3
- profession1
- profession2
- profession3
- ride
- search
- sensemotive
- sleightofhand
- spellcraft
- spot
- survival
- swim
- tumble
- usemagicdevice
- userope
- otherskill

**How to find out these names for yourself**

1. Goto the GitHub [Roll20 character sheet respository](https://github.com/Roll20/roll20-character-sheets)
2. Find the character sheet you want and go [into it's folder](https://github.com/Roll20/roll20-character-sheets/tree/master/D%26D_3-5).
3. Click on [character's sheet html file](https://github.com/Roll20/roll20-character-sheets/blob/master/D%26D_3-5/charsheet_3-5.html).
4. Click on [RAW in the upper right corner of the screen](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Roll20/roll20-character-sheets/master/D%26D_3-5/charsheet_3-5.html).

Search for the @ symbol. You are looking for macros that will look this.

> {{checkroll=[[1d20 + [[@{str-mod}]] ]] }}